# How to set if meta_value is lower < than other meta_value in a get_posts array?

Tags: php, array

So I'm building this post query array:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'author'        =>  $publisher_info-ID,
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'posts_per_page'    => 150,
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'type',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array( 'campaign' ),
    ),
    array(
         'key'     => 'status',
         'value'   => 'active',
        ),
    ),
    
    'orderby'      => 'rand'
));
```

What I'm struggling is how to integrate two meta key comparison?

Let's say I have two meta keys `meta_key` A1 and `meta_key` A2.

Both have numbers in their `meta_value`.

What I want is to incorporate: A1 < A2 in the array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your `meta_query` contains a taxonomy query that should be in the `tax_query` arg, and you're also missing `>` here: `$publisher_info-ID` ...

Answer (score -1):

Use this type of code :

```
$args = array(
    'author'        =>  $publisher_info->ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'type',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'campaign' ),
            )
        ),
    'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                    'key' => 'status',
                    'value' => 'active',
                    'compare' => '='),
            array(
                    'key' => 'B',
                    'value' => '1',
                    'compare' => '!=')
            )
);
$data = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: thanks, the     `array(
         'key'     => 'status',
         'value'   => 'active',
        ),` is missing, can you please add that part as well? thanks!

Comment: I provided you example you change compare meta value according to your need :
you change key B and value 1 with your second value which you need to campare with key status and value active.